# It is easy to bypass the "Are you paying attention?" tests

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-abuse

The *Are-You-Paying-Attenion?*<sup>TM</sup> review system is easily gameable and thus ineffective against people mindlessly reviewing posts for badges.

It is sufficient to make a downvote your first review action on any post:

- if the entry was an audit, the site will tell you so ("congratulations") and pass you to the next review.
- otherwise, undownvote and select whichever review action you please...

Following this simple procedure allows robo-reviewers to keep on "reviewing" at blazing speed.

Comment: Are there only negative reviews? Surely reviews that expect a positive or neutral response would be failed by this?

Comment: If Undo action is taken (one can undo only if a Post is genuine) then you can Take whichever action you wanted to take.

Comment: You don't even have to take any action (downvoting at first). You can simply click on "flag". If it was an audit, you immediately pass, else the flag menu pops up and you can click on "no action". It's also fewer clicks so even faster.

Comment: My favourite part of this post is the "The Are-You-Paying-Attenion" typo - very witty.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Fortunately, it's easy to spot these people in our statistics. Only two people had gamed the system in this manner on SO in the last month, and both will be taking a vacation from reviewing as a result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were right, there was no "known good post" audit in the first-post review queue. It's implemented now and should be available as soon as the next release rolls out. So expect to come across one soon.